# How do I check the size of a Go project?

Tags: go, project

Is there an easy way to check the size of a Golang project? It's not an executable, it's a package that I'm importing in my own project.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "size"?

Comment: I mean the size in bytes.

Comment: The size *of what*? Of the source files? Of the resulting executable?

Comment: @Faminha102 thinking about this Q some more:  focusing on pkg sizes (based on their library file-size) does not give the full picture. I've update the answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see how big the library binaries are by looking in the `$GOPATH/pkg` directory (if `$GOPATH` is not exported `go` defaults to `$HOME/go`).

So to check the size of some of the `gorilla` http pkgs. Install them first:

```
$ go get -u github.com/gorilla/mux
$ go get -u github.com/gorilla/securecookie
$ go get -u github.com/gorilla/sessions
```

The KB binary sizes on my 64-bit MacOS (`darwin_amd64`):

```
$ cd $GOPATH/pkg/darwin_amd64/github.com/gorilla/
$ du -k *

284 mux.a
128 securecookie.a
128 sessions.a
```

**EDIT:**

Library (package) size is one thing, but how much space that takes up in your executable after the link stage can vary wildly. This is because packages have their own dependencies and with that comes extra *baggage*, but that baggage may be shared by other packages you import.

An example demonstrates this best:

**empty.go:**

```
package main

func main() {}
```

**http.go:**

```
package main

import "net/http"

var _ = http.Serve

func main() {}
```

**mux.go:**

```
package main

import "github.com/gorilla/mux"

var _ = mux.NewRouter

func main() {}
```

All 3 programs are functionally identical - executing zero user code - but their dependencies differ. The resulting binary sizes in `KB`:

```
$ du -k *

1028    empty
5812    http
5832    mux
```

What does this tell us? The core go pkg `net/http` adds significant size to our executable. The `mux` pkg is not large by itself, but it has an import dependency on  `net/http` pkg - hence the significant file size for it too. Yet the delta between `mux` and `http` is only `20KB`, whereas the listed file size of the mux.a library is `284KB`. So we can't simply add the library pkg sizes to determine their true footprint.

*Conclusion:*
The go linker will strip out a lot of baggage from individual libraries during the build process, but in order to get a true sense of how much extra *weight* importing certain packages, one has to look at all of the pkg's **sub-dependencies** as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can download all the `import`ed modules with `go mod vendor`, then count the lines of all the `.go` files that aren't test files:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "fmt"
   "io/fs"
   "os"
   "os/exec"
   "path/filepath"
   "strings"
)

func count(mod string) int {
   imp := fmt.Sprintf("package main\nimport _ %q", mod)
   os.WriteFile("size.go", []byte(imp), os.ModePerm)
   exec.Command("go", "mod", "init", "size").Run()
   exec.Command("go", "mod", "vendor").Run()
   var count int
   filepath.WalkDir("vendor", func(s string, d fs.DirEntry, err error) error {
      if strings.HasSuffix(s, ".go") && !strings.HasSuffix(s, "_test.go") {
         data, err := os.ReadFile(s)
         if err != nil {
            return err
         }
         count += bytes.Count(data, []byte{'\n'})
      }
      return nil
   })
   return count
}

func main() {
   println(count("github.com/klauspost/compress/zstd"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that makes use of https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages

I took the [example](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages#example-package) provided by the author, and slightly updated it with the demonstration binary available [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/tools/+/refs/tags/v0.1.5:go/packages/gopackages/main.go).

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sort"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages"
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    // Many tools pass their command-line arguments (after any flags)
    // uninterpreted to packages.Load so that it can interpret them
    // according to the conventions of the underlying build system.
    cfg := &packages.Config{Mode: packages.NeedFiles |
        packages.NeedSyntax |
        packages.NeedImports,
    }
    pkgs, err := packages.Load(cfg, flag.Args()...)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "load: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    if packages.PrintErrors(pkgs) > 0 {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Print the names of the source files
    // for each package listed on the command line.
    var size int64
    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        for _, file := range pkg.GoFiles {
            s, err := os.Stat(file)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            size += s.Size()
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("size of %v is %v b\n", pkgs[0].ID, size)

    size = 0
    for _, pkg := range allPkgs(pkgs) {
        for _, file := range pkg.GoFiles {
            s, err := os.Stat(file)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                continue
            }
            size += s.Size()
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("size of %v and deps is %v b\n", pkgs[0].ID, size)
}

func allPkgs(lpkgs []*packages.Package) []*packages.Package {
    var all []*packages.Package // postorder
    seen := make(map[*packages.Package]bool)
    var visit func(*packages.Package)
    visit = func(lpkg *packages.Package) {
        if !seen[lpkg] {
            seen[lpkg] = true

            // visit imports
            var importPaths []string
            for path := range lpkg.Imports {
                importPaths = append(importPaths, path)
            }
            sort.Strings(importPaths) // for determinism
            for _, path := range importPaths {
                visit(lpkg.Imports[path])
            }

            all = append(all, lpkg)
        }
    }
    for _, lpkg := range lpkgs {
        visit(lpkg)
    }
    return all
}
```