# Finding largest imported package in Go binary

Tags: go, dependencies

My project has a huge binary (23MB, usually only 11MB-ish), when I check the binary using `go tool`, but it shows per package name instead of per directly imported package on the project:

```
23 075 950 (23 MB)
go tool nm -sort size -size ApiServerQ | head -n 20

  fb12c0    4874612 r runtime.pclntab
  a741e0     669338 T github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/endpoints.init
  87a200     305452 T github.com/xdg/stringprep.init
 14d0c80      75600 D runtime.mheap_
 14c0ba0      65744 D runtime.trace
  fa0b60      38267 r runtime.findfunctab
 149c6a0      30720 D crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519.base
  62cd20      20993 T vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Seal
  faae40      20892 r runtime.typelink
  4a4680      20413 T unicode.init
 1497be0      19108 D vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm.decomps
 1493120      19105 D golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm.decomps
  628480      18589 T vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Open
 148f1a0      16256 D vendor/golang.org/x/net/idna.idnaValues
  5c9080      16152 T crypto/sha512.blockAMD64
 14bcce0      16064 D runtime.semtable
 14e6c80      15384 D github.com/klauspost/compress/zstd.fsePredef
 148b5a0      15360 D vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi.bidiValues
  485520      15154 T time.parse
  859d20      14875 T go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/operation.(*IsMaster).Result
```

Compared to my old one project (ScyllaDB):

```
16 699 093 (16 MB)
go tool nm -sort size -size UserMicro | head -n 20 
  c94140    3345240 r runtime.pclntab
  88fee0     625345 T github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/endpoints.init
 1026020      65744 D runtime.trace
  543070      32787 T github.com/yuin/gopher-lua/parse.yyParse
  715c60      30757 T github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go.tryConcreteValue
  ffeb60      30720 D crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519.base
  c87080      27476 r runtime.findfunctab
  64fae0      20993 T vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Seal
  499750      20065 T unicode.init
  70d400      19890 T github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go.setValue
  ffa0a0      19105 D vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm.decomps
  64b240      18589 T vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Open
  c8e8e0      17060 r runtime.typelink
  ff6120      16256 D vendor/golang.org/x/net/idna.idnaValues
  5c09d0      16152 T crypto/sha512.blockAMD64
 1022160      16064 D runtime.semtable
  ff26a0      14976 D vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi.bidiValues
  59e0c0      14842 T github.com/yuin/gopher-lua.init
  5eac20      14482 T crypto/sha256.block
  5c7bc0      14174 T encoding/asn1.parseField
```

And other older one (MemSQL+GORM):

```
15 438 537 (15 MB)
go tool nm -sort size -size MonolithI | head -n 20
  b24500    3556591 r runtime.pclntab
  ee3960      65744 D runtime.trace
  ebbf60      30720 D crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519.base
  b182e0      26236 r runtime.findfunctab
  652aa0      20993 T vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Seal
  46f7b0      20065 T unicode.init
  eb74a0      19105 D vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm.decomps
  64e200      18589 T vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Open
  b1f6a0      16520 r runtime.typelink
  eb3520      16256 D vendor/golang.org/x/net/idna.idnaValues
  5f8a00      16152 T crypto/sha512.blockAMD64
  edfaa0      16064 D runtime.semtable
  eafaa0      14976 D vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi.bidiValues
  5a3300      14482 T crypto/sha256.block
  5ffc90      14174 T encoding/asn1.parseField
  4ba780      13913 T time.parse
  8857e0      13733 T net/http.init
  7dd940      13729 T github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql.parseDSNParams
  7b21a0      12577 T github.com/kokizzu/gorm.(*Scope).buildCondition
  768030      12202 T database/sql.convertAssignRows
```

and the other one (PostgreSQL):

```
12 007 258 (12 MB)
go tool nm -sort size -size MonolithYOD | head -n 20
  9914a0    2696675 r runtime.pclntab
  c6d0c0      65744 D runtime.trace
  4667d0      22868 T unicode.init.ializers
  604f00      20993 T internal/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Seal
  987a40      19967 r runtime.findfunctab
  c4c340      19105 D internal/x/text/unicode/norm.decomps
  74bb00      19020 T github.com/tdewolff/minify/css.init.ializers
  600660      18589 T internal/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Open
  c483c0      16256 D internal/x/net/idna.idnaValues
  7a4de0      16186 T github.com/nfnt/resize.Resize
  5bc930      16152 T crypto/sha512.blockAMD64
  c69200      16064 D runtime.semtable
  7a8d20      14984 T github.com/nfnt/resize.resizeNearest
  5c4000      14964 T encoding/asn1.parseField
  c44ac0      14592 D internal/x/text/unicode/bidi.bidiValues
  55abc0      14482 T crypto/sha256.block
  6f7e10      13890 T net/http.init.ializers
  7bbb40      13555 T image/png.(*decoder).readImagePass
  98d680      12544 r runtime.typelink
  4d9bb0      12353 T encoding/json.(*decodeState).literalStore
```

and the other one (PostgreSQL):

```
14 127 727 (14 MB)
go tool nm -sort size -size MonolithL | head -n 20        
  a94080    2899496 r runtime.pclntab
  e095e0      75600 D runtime.mheap_
  df9500      65744 D runtime.trace
  73a9c0      35788 T github.com/tdewolff/minify/css.(*cssMinifier).minifyProperty
  d8e380      30720 D crypto/ed25519/internal/edwards25519.base
  845d10      26470 T github.com/golang/freetype/truetype.(*hinter).run
  744510      25126 T github.com/tdewolff/minify/css.init
  a895c0      23278 r runtime.findfunctab
  60a110      20993 T vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Seal
  472ff0      20413 T unicode.init
  d898c0      19108 D vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm.decomps
  605870      18589 T vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305.chacha20Poly1305Open
  d85940      16256 D vendor/golang.org/x/net/idna.idnaValues
  5ba1e0      16152 T crypto/sha512.blockAMD64
  df5640      16064 D runtime.semtable
  7cb220      16012 T github.com/nfnt/resize.Resize
  d81d40      15360 D vendor/golang.org/x/text/unicode/bidi.bidiValues
  4879e0      15154 T time.parse
  7cf0b0      14806 T github.com/nfnt/resize.resizeNearest
  56b880      14482 T crypto/sha256.block
```

The question is, which package that causes this bloat? because it took time to upload the binary to the server if without external CI/CD (even after upx and ldflags-s-w), or which one of project's direct import that indirectly import that huge package?

Already tried `gofat` but it didn't show correct package name (it shows obfuscated package name), also tried `goweight` but it shows `exit status 1`.

Comment: With the sub-dependency nature of package imports it's difficult to get the root culprit. Package X & Y may show "bloat" but they both may depending on package Z which is the real bloat. You could run some empirical testing on import size using `side effect` imports as outline in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55132813/1218512) to get a better sense of the _hot spots_.

Comment: Showing 20 of the entries in the symbol table is unlikely to show a single big "thing".  It's entirely possible that the dependency tree is simply larger and added a lot of small things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, [goweight](https://github.com/jondot/goweight) solves the problem, apparently I was running `goweight` in wrong directory before. I also found out that `redis.v7` and `aws-sdk-go` that imported by `overseer/fetcher` (checked by [depth](https://github.com/KyleBanks/depth)) is the culprit.

```
goweight . | head -n 20
  8.7 MB github.com/go-redis/redis/v7
  7.3 MB github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3
  3.9 MB net/http
  3.8 MB runtime
  3.3 MB github.com/gocql/gocql
  2.8 MB github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/endpoints
  2.5 MB github.com/valyala/fasthttp
  1.9 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
  1.8 MB net
  1.8 MB crypto/tls
  1.5 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/operation
  1.5 MB golang.org/x/sys/unix
  1.4 MB reflect
  1.2 MB github.com/xdg/stringprep
  1.2 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec
  1.2 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver
  1.1 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsonrw
  1.0 MB github.com/klauspost/compress/zstd
  998 kB math/big
  916 kB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/topology
```

```
depth . | less
  │ ├ github.com/jpillora/overseer/fetcher
  │ │ ├ compress/gzip
  │ │ ├ encoding/json
        ...
  │ │ ├ net/http
  │ │ ├ os
  │ │ ├ github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws
```

**Update** After downgrading to [redis.v5](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/issues/1284) and updating to [latest](https://github.com/jpillora/overseer/issues/44) overseer that removes aws-sdk, also removing gocqlx it reduces to 18MB (13MB if using ldflags-s-w, 4MB if using upx)

```
goweight . | head -n 20
  3.9 MB net/http
  3.8 MB runtime
  3.0 MB gopkg.in/redis.v5
  2.5 MB github.com/valyala/fasthttp
  1.9 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
  1.8 MB net
  1.8 MB crypto/tls
  1.5 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/operation
  1.5 MB golang.org/x/sys/unix
  1.4 MB reflect
  1.2 MB github.com/xdg/stringprep
  1.2 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsoncodec
  1.2 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver
  1.1 MB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/bsonrw
  1.0 MB github.com/klauspost/compress/zstd
  998 kB math/big
  916 kB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/mongo/driver/topology
  847 kB syscall
  828 kB go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/x/bsonx
  802 kB gopkg.in/mgo.v2/internal/json
```